# How to deploy a .wim image to new system

Tags: windows, deployment, wim

I have a .wim of a standard image to be used to deploy new machines at my organization. Does anyone know how I can take that image, put it on a bootable USB stick and deploy it and install the new machine using it?

Comment: Do you mean ***WIM*** image?

Comment: Yes. Sorry that's it

Comment: It's tough to say for certain without familiarity of the WIM's contents and metadata. If it's a generic WIM, perhaps you could boot into a WinPE drive and apply it with ImageX or DISM?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj979690(v=winembedded.81).aspx

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744530(v=ws.10).aspx